# .replace example in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

Going through some introductory classes in python and came across a manipulation as follows:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
```

Can someone explain the first part of the replace? Not quite sure how to interpret all the special characters. Thanks.

Comment: its called a regular expression ... you can paste it into regex101.com or whatever and it will break it down for you ... basically replace everything between some opening parenthesis and some closing parenthesis with an empty string

Comment: In this specific case, it looks like it's deleting everything between the outermost set of parentheses (that follow a space?) in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace):

```py
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Your example appears to be trying to replace a regex pattern, but as far as I'm aware, `str.replace()` doesn't support regex.

You might be looking for [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Here's an example.

```py
import re

energy['Country'] = re.sub(r' \(.*\)','',energy['Country'])
```

This code will delete anything between parentheses in `energy['Country']`. The regex  matches a space, `\(` matches a left paren, `.` matches any non-line-break character, `*` allows an unlimited number of those, and `\)` matches a right paren. This regex searches for any text between parentheses that follows a space. The replacement argument in `re.sub()` in this case is an empty string, so the string `Hello (World)` will get replaced with `Hello`. Note the space, parentheses, and all text contained inside parentheses that's not a line break get matched and replaced.

[RegExr](https://regexr.com/) is a handy online tool to test and explain regular expressions.

[Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) provides comprehensive explanations of how regex works.

---

Edit: [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11411686/christian-reall-fluharty) pointed out that the code appears to be using [`pandas.Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

In this case, regex is indeed supported directly. The question's code simply replaces all occurrences of the regex pattern (which matches text enclosed within parentheses that follow a space, the parentheses themselves, and their preceding space) with an empty string and overwrites the existing series `energy['Country']` with the parenthesis-stripped version.

Comment: Based on [a github search for the code](https://github.com/search?q=%22energy%5B%27Country%27%5D.str.replace%28r%22+%5C%28.*%5C%29%22%2C%22%22%29%22&type=Code) it looks like this is being applied to a pandas dataframe column. The `str` attribute of a `Series` is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)